# Python caldav install failing for Python 2.7 on Windows

Tags: python, lxml, caldav

Trying to use easy_install to install caldav for Python 2.7.  lxml is failing and I've found binary installers for it for all versions of Python except 2.7.

Using easy_install I'm getting the following:

```
Running lxml-2.3.4\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\jimste~1\appdata\lo
cal\temp\easy_install-vhvbst\lxml-2.3.4\egg-dist-tmp-qs4ol2
Building lxml version 2.3.4.
Building without Cython.
ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt
warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree.c' under directory 'src\lxml'
warning: no files found matching 'lxml.objectify.c' under directory 'src\lxml'
warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree.h' under directory 'src\lxml'
warning: no files found matching 'lxml.etree_api.h' under directory 'src\lxml'
warning: no files found matching 'etree_defs.h' under directory 'src\lxml'
warning: no files found matching 'pubkey.asc' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching 'tagpython*.png' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching 'Makefile' under directory 'doc'
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

lxml if failing.  Any idea how I can get it installed on Windows for Python 2.7?

Thanks -Jim

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this today.  There is a Windows binary install for lxml for Python 2.7 located here:  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml